# as.character usage on functions

Tags: r, function

I stumbled uppon one problem:

```
temp.fun <- function() {}
as.character(temp.fun)
```

yields an error. I undersand, why it is not possible to "convert" a function into a character.
Question is, what properties to add to a function so that the method `as.character` returns a string defined by myself?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`deparse` can help:

```
> deparse( temp.fun )
[1] "function () " "{"            "}"
```

Going further with the details of your comment, what you can do is create a class that derives `function` and pass this instead of the function.

```
setClass( "myFunction", contains = "function" )
setMethod( "as.character", "myFunction", function(x, ...){
    deparse( unclass( x ) ) 
} )
```

So that when you pass a function to the third party package, you pass a `myFunction` instead:

```
f <- new( "myFunction", function(){} )
as.character(f)
# [1] "function () " "{"            "}"
```

Comment: also possibly  useful: `as.character(body(temp.fun))`

Comment: I understand, that there are several ways to retrieve characters from a function. But what I need is that `as.character` function works. To put some background: A library is using `as.character` internally on given parameters to name the results. When I give a function as a parameter it will not work. I'm just wondering if it is possible to add information to 'function' such as `as.character` would work.

Comment: I added content to my answer. Hope this helps.